# Do I need to close the input stream manually after using IOUtils.toString(input) of commons-io?

Tags: java, io, apache-commons-io

[Commons-IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) has an `IOUtils.toString(inputStream)` method, which can read all content from an input stream:

```
InputStream input = getInputStream();
String content = IOUtils.toString(input);
```

My question is shall I close the input stream manually after using it?

I thought IOUtils may close it since it has read all the content, but I can't find that in the source code.

Comment: If you can't find that in the source code, isn't it a strong indication that it isn't there?

Comment: For files, use FileUtils.readFileToString(), it uses IOUtils, but also closes the stream.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[The javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) says:

> Wherever possible, the methods in this class do not flush or close the stream. This is to avoid making non-portable assumptions about the streams' origin and further use. Thus the caller is still responsible for closing streams after use.

Comment: This is the conventional pattern for stream based libraries. The client should handle it.

Comment: Thank you, but I found I never need to do other operations on the input stream when I reading the content by `IOUtils.toString`, except closing it ...

Comment: for files you can use FileUtils.readFileToString() that closes the stream

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and InputStream is now AutoCloseable so you can do:

```
try(InputStream input = getInputStream())
```